# Django Iterating Over CheckboxSelectMultiple Renders Numbers

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, widget, django-widget

I'm trying to iterate over a MultipleSelect form that utilizes a CheckboxSelectMultiple widget and display each checkbox within. Here is the code for the iteration:

```
{% for choice in form.mp4_rasters %}
       <label class="checkbox inline">
          {{ choice }}
       </label>
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the Form I declared:

```
from django import forms

MP4_CHOICES = ('240p', '360p', '720p', '1080p')
WEBM_CHOICES = MP4_CHOICES
OGG_CHOICES = MP4_CHOICES
MISC_CHOICES = ('MP3', 'Roku')

class BatchSubmitForm(forms.Form):
    video_file = forms.FileField()
    framerate = forms.FloatField()
    title = forms.CharField()
    destination = forms.CharField()
    mp4_rasters = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=MP4_CHOICES)
    webm_rasters = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=WEBM_CHOICES)
    ogg_rasters = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=OGG_CHOICES)
    misc_rasters = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=MISC_CHOICES)
```

When rendering, I would expect it to output each checkbox with the name I passed in, but instead of "240p", "360p", etc. I get numbers (4, 6, 2, 0) for each checkbox. I also tried rendering based on the widget's choices, using the following code, as an alternative:

```
{% for choice in form.mp4_rasters.field.widget.choices %}
           <label class="checkbox inline">
              {{ choice }}
           </label>
    {% endfor %}
```

That code renders the names appropriately, but then it doesn't include a checkbox. What can I add to either to make it render the checkboxes as well as the appropriate names as defined in the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
MP4_CHOICES = ('240p', '360p', '720p', '1080p')
```

to

```
MP4_CHOICES = (('240p', '240p'), 
               ('360p', '360p'), 
               ('720p', '720p'), 
               ('1080p', '1080p'))
```

The reason you are seeing the numbers is, `choices` expects a tuple, and since you are not providing it a tuple, it is doing this.

`('240p')` is being evaluated as `('2', '4', '0', 'p')` , and it is getting `('2', '4', '0', 'p')[1]` to display in the dropdown. Hence the `(4, 6, 2, 0)`.